# Go to where function is DEFINED not DECLARED and bypassing String creation

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I'm trying to debug unmanaged C++ code which uses a template and I have 2 questions I couldn't find answers to:

1. When I "Navigate to Definition" OR "Navigate to Declaration" it only goes to the declaration in the header file, not to where the function is defined as I need it to. Any ideas how to quickly go to where it shows how the function is created? (I'm coming from C#)
2. When I "Step Into" it always goes through multiple string definitions (such as XString, etc) and I have to Step Out, Step In, Step Out, and Step In again which really sucks. Is there any way to bypass this inconvenience?

Using VS 2013.

Comment: where the definition is written? in .inl or .cpp file?

Comment: Declared in the .h file, defined in the .cpp. I want to navigate directly to the definition in the .cpp file but it will only navigate to the header file definition which is useless to me and in such a large code base, it takes a long time trying to "Find all References" and search for it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Definition for class methods that uses template parameters should be in the header file, is it the case? do you mean the definition is also there (not inlined/ may be outside class declaration), but not going to that? `F12` should go to method definition.
2. If you step-in, you have to step-out. Use *F10* to *step-over*.

Comment: 1. That is correct; they are defined in the header file. My problem is that I always have to "Find All References" and search for where the function is defined (void Numbers::DoThis(string[] a) {for each...} instead of just going to void DoThis(string[] a) which does nothing for me when I want to see what the function does).

Answer (score 1):

In C++, the template declaration is the definition. The compiler will generate the necessary machine code for different instantiations, but there won't be any generated source for you to step in to. And that's okay, because all functions would all be the same. Variables will resolve the the correct type, so you can do whatever you would do in a "real" function.

As for stepping over functions (string constructors and the like) C++ is definitely not C#. Have a look at this [from the MSDN blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andypennell/archive/2004/02/06/69004.aspx). I haven't tried it, it isn't supported, and it doesn't explicitly call out VS2013, but it might help you out.

Comment: 1. Apologies for the confusion, I know you can't Navigate to Definition while debugging, I just wanted it to go to where the function actually does something rather than where it is named in the header file.
2. Thanks, I guess I just have to accept this one. I've gotten a bit better with F11, Shift-F11, F11 so it's not as inconvenient as when I first started, but I appreciate the effort trying to solve my problem!